# Why does .dropna().apply() on a dataframe actually work?

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, null, apply

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, np.nan, 1, 1]})
```

When having to deal with nan values, I'm used to handle them with `loc` or `pd.notna()` etc., e.g.

```
df.loc[df.foo.notna(),"foo"] = df.loc[df.foo.notna()]["foo"]+1
df["foo"] = df["foo"].apply(lambda x: [...] if pd.notna(x) else np.nan)
```

because my understanding is/was that both sides need to match in length.

Why then is it possible to do this here

```
df["foo"] = df["foo"].dropna().apply(lambda x: x+1)
```

since `len(df["foo"])` is 4 while `len(df["foo"].dropna())` is 3. It doesn't match with what I "thought" I had understood.

Thanks for your help